# Why is 'if and only if' used here?

Tags: pragmatics

Would anyone please enlighten me on why the author uses 'if and only if' here? It sounds to me as though just 'if' sufficed for him to inform the readers 'Cats are her favourite animals' is the truth condition.

---

Implicature

A communicated implication of an utterance. A speaker can intend to mean
more by her utterance than what the words that she utters mean, as the
philosopher Paul Grice pointed out.

> Andy: I think we should get a pet.
>
> Bess: Cats are my favourite animals.

Here Bess’s utterance is true **if and only if** cats are her favourite animals.
However, in the context, it is likely that she conveyed more, in making her
utterance, than this (and that she intended to do so). She intentionally and
openly implied that she and Andy should get a cat (or cats) as pets. Pragmatic theorists would say that she implicated that she and Andy should get a cat (or cats) as pets.

[...]

(source: [Key Terms in Pragmatics](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lkcdCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA92&dq=%22Bess%20Cats%20are%20my%20favourite%20animals%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Bess%20Cats%20are%20my%20favourite%20animals%22&f=false))

Comment: this is really an academic point. The author is talking about how "a speaker can intend to mean more by her utterance than what the words that she utters mean". Here, what Bess said is true only if she is speaking the truth without any ulterior motive of sending across a different signal. But as the author further points out, it here implies that she is suggesting they get cats as pets.

Comment: It is simply a way of providing emphasis to *if*.

Comment: There are conditions where "if" may be interpreted ambiguously.  (The whole Boolean algebra problem.)  The idiom removes that ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason *if and only if* has a meaning here different from it's usual meaning in mathematics?

From [www.mathwords.com](http://www.mathwords.com/i/if_and_only_if.htm), for example:

> **if and only if Biconditional**
>
> A way of writing two conditionals at once: both a conditional and its
>   converse.
>
> For example, the statement "A triangle is equilateral **if and only if** its angles
>   all measure 60°" means both "If a triangle is equilateral then its
>   angles all measure 60°" and "If all the angles of a triangle measure
>   60° then the triangle is equilateral".
>
> Biconditionals can be written using the ⇔ symbol:
>
> A triangle is equilateral ⇔ its angles all measure 60°

So:

> If Beth's statement is true, then cats are Beth's favourite animals.
>
> AND
>
> If cats are Beth's favourite animals, then Beth's statement is
>    true.
>
> That is:
>
> Beth's statement is true ⇔ Cats are Beth's favourite animals
>
> Beth's statement is true **if and only if** cats are Beth's favourite animals.

I agree that Beth appears to be saying more, that if Andy and Beth should get a pet, they should consider getting a cat, provided that cats are Beth's favorite animals.

Comment: The [relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) says ***if and only if** (shortened **iff**) is a biconditional logical connective between statements.* I knew about **OR/XOR**, but until now I hadn't really registered this **IF/IFF** distinction. But it's obviously potentially useful.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Right re Wikipedia. I opted for what seemed a simpler reference with a good example, and I omitted *iff*.

Comment: I must admit that until I factored in this two-way "biconditional" concept it seemed to me the cited passage just said that a statement is true ***if*** the condition it asserts is true - a trite observation, within which context it seems pretty meaningless to include ***and only if***. I actually thought the **⇔** symbol meant something like **is another way of saying**, or **can be restated as**, but the "two-way" aspect comes into play with two assertions such as *A:Beth won the lottery. B:Beth is rich,* where A "entails, implies" B, but B doesn't necessarily imply A.

Comment: The terminology, "if and only if," is an unfortunate but established bit of mathematical jargon. It was fought by some mathematicians, notably by the R. L. Moore  school, but it was championed by Paul Halmos, who introduced the abbreviation, iff. There is a simple gedanken experiment to see tha it is jargon. t